# Link people to organizational Units in a LDAP DIT tree

Tags: unix, ldap, openldap

I am constructing a LDAP just to learn about it. I am new working with LDAP.

I have a representation of the people inside a company in a individual group called "people".
 
Now I would like put (link) this people in the different ous, for example
Mike pertain a energy sector, member of board_directors and seniors.
Sue pertain a water sector, member of board_directors
and
Peter pertain a water sector, member of assembly group and seniors.

Is it possible?, How can I link this people under branch ou=people to another ous?

I have a LDAP DIT Tree like this:

```
dn: dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: xd
dc: company

dn: ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: people
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: people working in my company


dn: ou=areas,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: areas
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: distinct zones in my company


dn: ou=sectors,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: sectors
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: distinct sectors


dn: ou=water,ou=sectores,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: water
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: reference to water sector


dn: ou=energy,ou=sectores,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: energy
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: reference to energy sector


dn: ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: orga
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: distintos organismos da organizacion


dn: ou=board_directors,ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: board_directors
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: The company board of directors


dn: ou=assembly,ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: assembly
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: weekly assembly organizators


dn: ou=seniors,ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: seniors
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: main company seniors


dn: ou=it,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: it
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: it resources


dn: ou=data,ou=it,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: data
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: data


dn: ou=apps,ou=it,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: apps
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: applications


dn: ou=machines,ou=it,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: machines
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: something mechanic


dn: uid=Sue,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
description: User posix Sue
sn: Reyes
givenName: Sue
cn: Sue Reyes
displayName: Sue Reyes
homeDirectory: /home/Sue
uid: Sue
uidNumber: 1003
gidNumber: 1003
userPassword:: MTIzNA==


dn: uid=peter,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
uid: peter
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
description: user posix peter
sn: Griffin
givenName: Peter
cn: peter griffin
displayName: Peter Griffin
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 1001
homeDirectory: /home/peter
userPassword:: MTIzNA==

dn: uid=mike,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
uid: mike
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
description: user posix Mike
sn: Larson
givenName: Mike
cn: Mike Larson
displayName: Mike Larson
uidNumber: 1002
gidNumber: 1002
homeDirectory: /home/Mike
userPassword:: MTIzNA==
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you almost answered your own question. Your users are in a container called people.  You want to put them in different groups.  Rather than create containers for all of your different organizational units (i.e. board_directors, it, etc) you could create groups for those things.

```
dn: ou=groups,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: groups
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=board_directors,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=Sue,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
uniqueMember: uid=Mike,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com

dn: cn=it,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=Peter,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
```

It may be that not all of your organizational units fir neatly into groups.

Perhaps it might be necessary to organize groups under organizations for instance.

```
dn: ou=groups,ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
ou: groups
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: cn=board_directors,ou=groups,ou=orga,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=Mike,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com

dn: cn=board_directors,ou=groups,ou=orgb,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectClass: groupOfUniquenames
uniqueMember: uid=Sue,ou=people,dc=company,dc=xd,dc=com
```

These are just examples but I would lean towards using the `groupOfUniqueNames` objectclass to group people together.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I was searching somenthing like this. I'll use the groupOfUniquenames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the usage for your LDAP instance.
If this is used for authentication and as an attribute repository, then you should keep all your "people" entries in one container and manage each "attribute" to determine the type, department, location, etc.

Then, if required, place the users into groups based on the attribute values.

-jim